# Meaning of tags in vb.net project file

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a project (vbproj) and it has some tags I haven't seen before and googling doesn't lead me to anything useful (or I just have bad google-fu).

Anyway, does anyone know what these tags would be used for in a windows console application (outputtype is exes) or anywhere else for that matter?

```
<DefaultClientScript>JScript</DefaultClientScript>
<DefaultHTMLPageLayout>Grid</DefaultHTMLPageLayout>
<DefaultTargetSchema>IE50</DefaultTargetSchema>
```

Fairly sure they are just junk as far as the windows exe is concerned, but it'd be nice to change that to definitely junk.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/vslangproj80.vbprojectproperties3.defaultclientscript?view=visualstudiosdk-2022

Comment: @AndrewMorton: My mistake, most of the solution is for an asp.net site, but this is a related console application, so should just be vb .net.

Comment: @T.S. That link is indeed the first one that comes up when searching. However, it is spectacularly unhelpful, as it describes a property accessible via automation, with no further helpful information.

Comment: @T.S.: that basically boils down to "External components can access these properties through the Properties collection for the appropriate Visual Studio automation object" which doesn't explain what happens if I delete them or put war and piece inside the tags.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, those properties are only used for ASP.NET projects (old ones at that -- witness the references to IE 5.0 and JScript). I seem to remember them from the glory days of Visual Interdev and FrontPage. I'd say you could get rid of them with no ill effect.

Comment: https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/481228-where-defaultclientscript-property-vs-2005-a
anything in the project is either compilation or VS instruction. These must be tell VS that when you open HTML or scripting that when you add <script... it adds JScript. Why is this in console app? May be project was converted.